# One machine and two shells

Tags: ubuntu

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can two users simultaneously share one pc](https://superuser.com/questions/106842/can-two-users-simultaneously-share-one-pc)

Has anyone seen a program that can dispatch keystrokes from two different keyboards attached to a computer to two different shells? That said, I've attached an external monitor, mouse and keyboard to my laptop and I want to have one shell on my laptop's screen and another shell on my external monitor. I can do that but the problem is that the keyboards are shared between the two shells same with the mice.

I use ubuntu but I'm curious to see if there's a solution either in linux or windows.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish ultimately?

Comment: I knew we should never have thrown out those [VT520](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_terminal)s!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can two users simultaneously share one pc](http://superuser.com/questions/106842/can-two-users-simultaneously-share-one-pc) also [Setting up a multiseat configuration](http://superuser.com/questions/29879/setting-up-a-multiseat-configuration) and perhaps [multi monitor keyboard kiosk](http://superuser.com/questions/302172/multi-monitor-keyboard-kiosk)

Comment: @squillman I want to have to different consoles on the same machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best known tool to do this is named [pconsole](http://www.heiho.net/pconsole/).

> pconsole allows you to connect to each node of your cluster simultaneously, and you can type your administrative commands in a specialized window that 'multiplies' the input to each to the connections you have opened.

It was developed for clusters, but I think it should work just as you intended.

[ClusterSSH](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/clusterssh/index.php?title=Main_Page) also comes to mind.